# word for moving your head to keep staring at something

Tags: word-request

> "The dog tracked the bone with its head as the owner kept waving it at
> it."

Is tracked something with its head the best way to say this? I can't think of a simpler way to say this, but certainly there has to be, because I couldn't find any similar example on Google.

Another example would be:

> The audience tracked the ball with their heads as the tennis players
> kept hitting the ball.

Comment: I don't follow the logic.  Why does there have to be a simpler way to say this?  How would you say this in your language?

Comment: Nobody uses their heads to track anything. People stare at a ball, a dog, or whatever, with their eyes. Because this is so common, you don't even need to mention their eyes. You can just say *The audience followed every move of the ball as the players hit it back and forth*.

Comment: I was thinking that it's funnier to say that people are moving their heads while tracking something when you're writing a parody of a movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that doesn't sound idiomatic at all. We follow things with our *eyes* and only move our head to complement that.

You could say instead:

- The dog *followed the bone with his eyes*...
- The dog *kept his eyes fixed on the bone*...
- The dog *stayed focused on the bone*...

Avoid "stared at", because that can mean a fixed gaze.